# Young Adult Story about girl with electric powers

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this book in the early 2000s, possibly late 90s, about a teenage girl with electric powers.

Some scenes I remember are, that she’s in a shop to buy a dress with her dad’s credit card, and as she’s changing she gets teleported to the past (I think), wanders around and when she gets back to the shop she’s in the present.

In another scene, she gets attacked by some thugs and electrocutes them unknowingly. I remember one goes by the name Pluto and she mocks him for it, he pulls out a knife, then bam.

I honestly can’t remember the name of the book, but it may be part of a series. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Wow I can't believe I just came across this post after searching online for an hour trying to figure out what that book was that I read back in the 90s but couldn't remember, I was searching "book that had girl on cover with electricity hands" hahaha, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

### Could this be [*Aftershock*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1442414154)?

[image]

The protagonist has electric powers, as might be surmised from the cover.

> Kneeling down, I slammed my hands into the trail of water connecting
>   us. Instantly crackling threads of pink electricity ran through the
>   puddle and over the alien’s body, engulfing him in a deadly electric
>   glow.

She uses her father’s credit card to pay:

> I whipped out my daddy’s American Express Platinum card, which he had thoughtfully provided
>   for all my birthday shopping needs.

There is a character named Pluto:

> Fortunately Pluto was there to fill the gap. *”Aiiiyeee!”* he
>   screamed. “It’s *her!*”

And some time travel:

> “So,” I said slowly, “you think I wanted to see her so badly that I
>   somehow traveled backward in time?”

It is indeed part of a series.